# Is there a more pythonic way to convert a list of booleans to an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I feel silly having to ask this question, but my memory evades me of better alternatives. Two appraoches that spring to mind:

First:

```
def f1(v):
    return sum(2**i for i,va in enumerate(v) if va)

>>> f1([True, False, True])
5
```

Second:

```
def f2(v):
    return int('0b' + "".join(str(int(va)) for va in v),2)

>>> f2([True, False, True])
5
```

I feel that f1 is almost to clunky to be pythonic, and f2 is plainly too ugly as I'm jumping between multiple datatypes. Maybe its my age...?

Comment: Is there a reason you need the sum of the indices? Why can't you just do `sum(list_of_bools)` which in this case would equal `2`

Comment: @PyPingu They aren’t calculating the sum of the indices. They are interpreting the bools as a binary number where the first element is the ones, the second the twos place, the third the fours place and so on.

Comment: I get that there is actually more to it than simply summing the indices, but the question says "convert a list of bools to an integer" so I wondered if there was actually some reason that the straightforward sum wasn't what was required. FWIW I don't really see that `f1` is a bad solution if that's the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a left shift is slightly faster than raising to powers (at least on my machine).  Using a bitwise operation encourages the reader of the code to think in terms of binary data.

```
>>> sum(v << i for i, v in enumerate([True, False, True]))
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for contrast here's a way that you would do this if you were writing python as if you were writing something like c.

```
def f(l):
  output = 0
  for i in range(len(l)):
    output |= l[i] << i
  return output
```

Answer (score 1):

Using booleans in arithmetic operations (also lambda functions) is very pythonic:

```
lst = [True, False, True]

func = lambda x: sum(2 ** num * i for num, i in enumerate(x))

print(func(lst))
# 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another hacky way I came up with:

```
def f1(v):
    return int(''.join(str(int(b)) for b in v), 2)
```

Example:

```
>>> def f1(v):
...     return int(''.join(str(int(b)) for b in v), 2)
...
>>> f1([True, False, True])
5
>>>
```

Another identical example using `map` (more readable in my view):

```
def f1(v):
    return int(''.join(map(str, map(int, v))), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its little more rigid solution but its very **computationally efficient**

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> predefined_bytes = 2**(np.arange(32))
>>> predefined_bytes
array([         1,          2,          4,          8,         16,
               32,         64,        128,        256,        512,
             1024,       2048,       4096,       8192,      16384,
            32768,      65536,     131072,     262144,     524288,
          1048576,    2097152,    4194304,    8388608,   16777216,
         33554432,   67108864,  134217728,  268435456,  536870912,
       1073741824, 2147483648])


def binary2decimal(bits,predefined_bytes):
    bits = np.array(bits)
    return np.sum(bits*predefined_bytes[:bits.shape[0]])

>>> binary2decimal([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],predefined_bytes)
255
```